# Axios's response, what's in it??.....const response = await axios

Tags: axios

I'm using Axios in WP e.g.

```
const response = await axios.delete(universityData.siteURL + "/wp-json/wp/v2/note/" + thisNote.getAttribute("data-noteID"))
```

All works fine but what I don't understand is the structure / content of 'response'. How do I interrogate 'response'? I had assumed for instance if I did `console.log('Axios response: ' + response.data)` I'd get a nicely laid out JSON like OO output in the Chrome console panel. But all I see is: `Axios response: [object Object]`

I can do this `response.data.userNoteCount` and I get something sensible back. BTW 'userNoteCount' is a field I added to my JSON for my custom post type. But how else do I see all the content of response without specifically having to target it?

Comment: can you check through `console.log(respone)` directly?

Comment: `console.log(response)` also gives me ...Axios response: [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to another contributor elsewhere this is the answer:

> When you do the console.log you're adding the JSON object to the
> string of Axios Response, so the JSON object is being converted to a
> string, hence the object Object.
>
> If you do it as two seperate lines, like
>
> `console.log('Axios Response');`
> `console.log(response.data);`
>
> Then it will be outputted as the actual object.
>
> With it being an HTTP Request though, rather than outputting it into
> the console, what I'd do is open the Network tab of the browser
> development tools, and select the XHR tab, and then the request will
> appear in there and you can inspect the full response body there
> without having to log it.